# get values from nested textboxes in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I load data from an API and bind the values i get into  textfields which has a loop method on it.
Secondly what i want to do is when the values are been shown on the page and i submit click is click, it should post all the values to the console.

API

```
   this.http.get('http://localhost/scripts/test.php?year='+this.navparams.data.Quest_Year).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =>{
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                this.items= data;
            });
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
<ion-input  type="text"  [(ngModel)]="item.Quest_ID"></ion-input>
</div>
<button (click)="send()"> Sample</button>
```

JS

```
  send(){
    for(var i=0;i<this.test.length;i++) {
    console.log(item.Quest_ID[i])
    }

    }
```

Comment: what did you try ? any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your model is bound to item.Quest_ID which is an element in the items array, so, you should be doing this:

```
send(){
    for(var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++) {
        console.log(this.items[i].Quest_ID);
    }
}
```

to log them all to console.

or if you want to be cooler:

```
send(){
    this.items.forEach(item => console.log(item.Quest_ID));
}
```